# C# Convert a string to number

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a string "8.7" to a number, but all my tries convert it to 87 not to 8.7. Here is how I tried.

```
string wind_kph = "8.7"
if (Convert.ToDouble(wind_kph) > 60.00f)
```

true

```
if ((int)Convert.ToDouble(wind_kph) > 60.00f)
```

true

```
if (Convert.ToDecimal(wind_kph) > 60.00f)
```

true

Comment: Do you have any localization settings that could be interfering with the parse? I believe the decimal point is a comma in some cultures. The code you have looks like it *should* work though.

Comment: What is your local culture? Many Eurppean cultures treat `"8.7"` as `87`, and `"8,7"` as `8.7`; I suspect you can fix a lot here simply by explicitly specifying a culture (perhaps the invariant culture).

Comment: The first line should be ";" terminated. How it compiles w/syntax error? Rgds,

Comment: There is no problem with your code and it works fine when I tried with it.

Comment: @AlexBell you are right, the code is bigger and I resumed and forgot the ;

Comment: The problem was my language selection, fixed it with InvariantCulture Thanks

Comment: No problem. Actually, it's quite interesting question. Thanks for bringing it to our attention. Rgds,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `InvariantCulture` for parsing which uses `dot` as a decimal separator

```
if(double.Parse(wind_kph, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > 60.00)
```

You can find more detailed information from the documentation of [`double.Parse(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx) method, the relevant part is:

> The *s* parameter is interpreted using the formatting information in a `NumberFormatInfo` object that is initialized for the current thread culture. For more information, see `CurrentInfo`. To parse a string using the formatting information of some other culture, call the `Double.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)` or `Double.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)` method.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. My language selection was only recognizing a , not a .

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a culture problem. If not explicitly specified the parsing functions use the current thread culture. To specify a specific culture you can send a 2nd parameter to the `double.Parse` function. In your case for "." you can use `InvariantCulture`.

```
double.Parse("8.7", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```